# matching the down the lower float

Tags: python, math, rounding

there is a list of voltage that I need to find the closest number

`voltage_map= [11.65,11.75,11.85,11.95]`

I want to match to the closest and lowest number so I have the function below

```
def close_vol(list,K):
    return list[min(range(len(list)), key = lambda i: abs(list[i]-K))]
```

However, the function would return the closest but not the lowest.

when I set K = 11.70 `close_vol(voltage_map,11.70)`,it matched 11.75, whereas I expect it to round down to 11.65

when I set K = 11.84 `close_vol(voltage_map,11.84)`,it matched 11.85, I do want it to round down to 11.75

Anyone would know what should I add into the function above?

Comment: What is `voltage_map`? Without that, this isn't a [mcve].

Comment: voltage_map is the table of the picture above. Sorry for unclear info

Comment: `def close_vol(K)` This function is defined to take one argument.  But you're calling it with two arguments `close_vol(11,70)`.  I don't see how this code even runs.

Comment: Why not give a python literal for it rather than a screenshot that would require your readers to manually type it if they wanted to run your code?

Comment: Please improve your question with further information about the `voltage_map` variable. Otherwise, the question will be unclear.

Comment: Showing us a picture of a table does not really help.  Is that supposed to be a list?  Is it a dataframe?  Is it some other data type?  We can't tell from a picture.

Comment: When I define a list `voltage_map` with the displayed values and evaluate `close_vol(11.70)` I get `11.65`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [bisect module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) to discover where a given `k` falls withing `voltage_map`:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

voltage_map = [11.65,11.75,11.85,11.95,12.05,12.15,12.25,12.35,12.45,12.55,12.65,12.75]

def close_vol(k):
    i = max(0, bisect_left(voltage_map,k) - 1)
    return voltage_map[i]

#test

for k in [11.5 + (0.25)*k for k in range(7)]:
    print(k,close_vol(k))

'''
11.5 11.65
11.75 11.65
12.0 11.95
12.25 12.15
12.5 12.45
12.75 12.65
13.0 12.75
'''
```

Note that in this code any `k` which falls outside of the given voltage range is sent to the nearest voltage range endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to find the closest voltage that is below your inputted value?

Assuming that `voltages` is a list of the voltages that you've screenshotted, you could do something like this

```py
voltages = [11.65, 11.75, ...]
def close_vol(K):
    if K < min(voltages):
        raise ValueError("`K` is less than every voltage value")
    return max([i for i in voltages if K >= i])
```